# C# Create strings with all possible combinations

Tags: c#, string

So I have a method which takes a string. The string is built up from a constant value and 2 bools, 2 constant ints, and an int that can be 10,20 or 30. this will all be a string where the parameters are seperated by underscore.

Example:

```
string value = "horse"
string combination1 = value+"_true_false_1_1_20";
dostuff(combination1);
```

I need to run every single possible combination through

How do I take this constant value and run it through the method with all of the possible combinations ?

String built: "VALUE_BOOL1_BOOL2_CONSTINT1_CONSTINT2_INT1"

```
Possibilities
    VALUE = Horse
    BOOL1 = True, False
    BOOL2 = True, False
    CONSTINT1 = 1
    CONSTINT2 = 1,
    INT1 = 10, 20, 30
```

How can I take the predefined value string and create all possible combinations and run them through the doStuff(string combination) method ?

Comment: Try reading about loops: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a very readable LINQ statement without the use of loops:

```
public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{   
  var combis =
    from bool1 in new bool[] {true, false}
    from bool2 in new bool[] {true, false}
    let i1 = 1
    let i2 = 1
    from i3 in new int[] {10, 20, 30}
    select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

  return combis.ToList();
}
```

---

EDIT: Keep in mind that multiple arrays have to be created in the above solution because [the in-clause is evaluated multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975128/how-often-is-the-in-clause-evaluated-in-a-linq-query). You could change it to the following to circumvent this:

```
public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{
    bool[] bools = new[] {true, false};
    int[] ints = new[] {10, 20, 30};

    var combis =
        from bool1 in bools
        from bool2 in bools
        let i1 = 1
        let i2 = 1
        from i3 in ints
        select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

    return combis.ToList();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Probably you should also keep an eye on my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975128/how-often-is-the-in-clause-evaluated-in-a-linq-query) which discusses the performance of this method.