# How often is the In-Clause evaluated in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I just answered on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974998/c-sharp-create-strings-with-all-possible-combinations) with the following LINQ query, that returns a list of certain string combinations:

```
public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{   
  var combis =
    from bool1 in new bool[] {true, false}
    from bool2 in new bool[] {true, false}
    let i1 = 1
    let i2 = 1
    from i3 in new int[] {10, 20, 30}
    select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

  return combis.ToList();
}
```

What I now ask myself: Is each in-clause (e.g., `... in new bool[] {true, false}`) evaluated only once or multiple times, i.e., is there only one array created of multiple ones per in-clause?

---

Update:

As the answers indicate, it is evaluated multiple times. I will change the code to

```
public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{
    bool[] bools = new[] {true, false};
    int[] ints = new[] {10, 20, 30};

    var combis =
        from bool1 in bools
        from bool2 in bools
        let i1 = 1
        let i2 = 1
        from i3 in ints
        select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

    return combis.ToList();
}
```

so that no multiple arrays have to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is evaluated multiple times. Query expressions have a specified translation to method calls. I used Resharper to perform that conversion. Avert your eyes...

```
new bool[] { true, false }
.SelectMany(bool1 => new bool[] { true, false }, (bool1, bool2) => new { bool1, bool2 })
.Select(@t => new { @t, i1 = 1 })
.Select(@t => new { @t, i2 = 1 })
.SelectMany(@t => new int[] { 10, 20, 30 }, (@t, i3) => "" + "_" + @t.@t.@t.bool1 + "_" + @t.@t.@t.bool2 + "_" + @t.@t.i1 + "_" + @t.i2 + "_" + i3);
```

For each `bool1`, a new array is being created.

It really can't be any other way. What if you had written the following?

```
from bool1 in new [] { true, false }
from bool2 in new [] { bool1 } //dependent on bool1!
```

The inner sequence can be generated depending on all range variables that are in scope. It is dynamic.

Could the C# compiler optimize this away, though? It can't because it is not allowed to know that `Enumerable.SelectMany` does not depend on the object identity of the sequences passed in. It could, for example, print each hash code to the console.

Answer (score 1):

This can be tested as follows (code for LINQPad):

```
void Main()
{
    Combis("");
}

private static bool[] Test(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("!{0}", arg);
    return new bool[] {true, false};
}

public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{
  var combis =
    from bool1 in Test("A")
    from bool2 in Test("B")
    let i1 = 1
    let i2 = 1
    from i3 in new int[] {10, 20, 30}
    select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

  return combis.ToList();
}
```

Output:

```
!A
!B
!B
```

You can see that `Test("A")` was called once, and `Test("B")` was called twice.

---

We can also consider the int array:

```
void Main()
{
    Combis("");
}

private static bool[] TestBool(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("!{0}", arg);
    return new bool[] {true, false};
}

private static int[] TestInt(string arg)
{
    Console.WriteLine("!{0}", arg);
    return new int[] {10, 20, 30};
}

public static List<String> Combis(string value)
{
  var combis =
    from bool1 in TestBool("A")
    from bool2 in TestBool("B")
    let i1 = 1
    let i2 = 1
    from i3 in TestInt("C")
    select value + "_" + bool1 + "_" + bool2 + "_" + i1 + "_" + i2 + "_" + i3;

  return combis.ToList();
}
```

Output:

```
!A
!B
!C
!C
!B
!C
!C
```

We see that `TestInt("C")` is called twice after each call to `TestBool("A")` (of which there are two) for a total of four times.

---

It is correct that moving the initialization of the arrays as presented in the updated question will preven the double initialization.